# CSS in Classic ASP vs ASP.Net 3.5?

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, hover

With an ASP.net 1.0 site the following worked with the CSS. But we are upgrading the site to asp 3.5 and I think the CSS is no longer valid.  Is this true for the Active and Hover CSS?

```
 .BodyText
{
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
    color: Black;

}
:active.BodyText
{
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
    text-decoration: None;
}
:hover.BodyText
{
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CSS isn't affected by the version of ASP or ASP.NET you are using.

You have to look at the HTML that is being generated and make sure you are appropriately using the class names from you CSS.

**EDIT**

As others have said, it also looks like your selectors are backwards (not sure if this is a typo or not). They should be:

```
.BodyText { }

.BodyText:active { }

.BodyText:hover { }
```

Comment: See my comment on Brett's post.

Answer (score 3):

If you see a diffence in how CSS is interpreted, it's not because of the version of ASP you are using. The most likely reason is that you have a different `doctype` tag in your pages.

The version of HTML (which the `doctype` tag specifies) will have some effect on how CSS works, and the difference between not having one and having one is even bigger.

For example, without a `doctype` (Quirks Mode) CSS identifiers might be case insensetive (depending on the browser brand and version), while having a valid `doctype` (Standards Compliance Mode) CSS identifiers are case sensetive.

The version of Visual Studio that you are using may have influenced the choise of `doctype`, if you just use the templates for web pages straight off. Newer versions come with templates that have a `doctype` with a newer HTML version.

Comment: +1 really good point, the doctype may have gotten stricter, with XHTML as one possibility

Answer (score 2):

I the css selector should be: `.BodyText:hover` instead of the reverse, but as Justin Niessner mentioned, your ASP.NET version will not affect the CSS

Comment: `:hover.BodyText` is a valid selector. It's just a convention that pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements come after other simple selectors.

Comment: @BoltClock - (well, I guess I don't know what the HTML looks like), but won't that affect the `.BodyText` within the hovered element? (I did make an assumption that he wanted the `.BodyText:hover` selector

Comment: @Brett: No, it affects an element if it's hovered and it's a `.BodyText`. What you have in mind is space-separated: `:hover .BodyText`.

Comment: @BoltClock - so does that mean `.BodyText:hover` and `:hover.BodyText` are the exact same?

Comment: Yes. Sorry that wasn't clear :S